# How do I position UIView in superview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, frame, bounds

Im adding a UIImageView with a UIImage which I wish to appear in the center top of the main UIView.

I will be using a UIPageControl to swipe that view off to the left and bring in the new one from the right.  I have added the UIImageView which normally just adds it to the bottom right corner

```
-(void)createUIViews{
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GiftCard.png"];
    firstView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    firstView.tag = 1;
    firstView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
}
```

Now I wish to position it at top center.  So Im thinking of something like this:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x += 50;
    self.view.frame = newFrame;

    [self.view addSubview:firstView];
```

But when I add this code at the bottom of the previous one, (which btw is being called from viewDidLoad), the image still appears at the bottom right.  How do I position it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code to viewDidAppear. Bounds and frames are not guaranteed to have been set till viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear.

Comment: Ok now I need to move animate it, from the UIPageControl, should I make another post?

Comment: Yes, I would make another post for animation since that is a more involved process.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set your struts and springs appropriately and then just do this:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
  {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    firstView.center = self.center;
  }
```